# How to cluster correlated pages into segments?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My site basically contains 4 page types :

- Navigation pages, leading to one of below
- Product Pages, containing product information and relevant article links
- Content Pages, or articles going into detail on whatever topic
- Escalation Pages, like contact or chat

I want to understand what the best way would be to cluster these together as segments, so I can get a better understanding of my customers behavior.

My URL structure is allowing me to simply relate a page to a cluster, for instance, if it has /content/ in the url, it's an article, if it has /product/ in the url it's a product page, and so on.

However, how do I transform this structure to segments as in following scenarios :

Scenario 1 : People on my site that **only** visited pages containing /content/

Scenario 2 : People on my site that visited url's containing /content/ **AND** /product/ **but nothing else**

etc.

Is this even possible with GSA or should I take a different approach? The essence is that I need to be able to get a better visibility on areas that need attention.

For instance people reading an article and then leaving are a positive outcome, as they were (presumably) able to support themselves.
People reading an article but needing contact afterwards could mean that content needs to be improved, and people just contacting me without even reading articles might require a bit of encouragement to try something first

Any ideas, suggestions ?

I'm capable of using the API, just need to have a better insight on how the queries should be constructed to define proper segments.

Comment: Google Analytics has introduced content groupings for exactly that purpose - however I'm not sure if this is on-topic for SO since this is more about configuration then progamming (it's possible to create content groupings in code but with your url structure it would be easier to create them in the interface).

Comment: Thanks Eike, I wasn't aware of this option. Not sure that it will suit all the needs but I'll take a look at it.